# Disable Compression in WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.x

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, websphere-liberty

I have a web application that is running on WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.x, which is located in a private LAN. I have set up an IIS reverse proxy in a DMZ that points to the application server in the LAN and has a URL Rewrite outbound rule. URL Rewrite outbound rules will not work if the content is compressed.

I have zero experience with WebSphere, and the people who set up the application server are unavailable. I have searched and can't find any answers -- at least that I can understand with my lack of experience.

So, is there a way to disable compression in WebSphere Liberty Profile 8.5.x, and if so, how exactly do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I didn't need to change any WebSphere Liberty settings at all. Here's how I fixed it:

1. In the URL Rewrite module, I added the HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING server variable.
2. In the Server Variables section of the Inbound Rule, I added HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING with an arbitrary value (I used "asdf") and set Replace to true.
3. I edited the web.config, and changed the value of "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" serverVariables node to an empty string.

Now IIS only accepts non-compressed responses, and the Outbound Rule works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with some reverse proxy config, I'd suggest you to install supported WebSphere Plugin for IIS.

You can download it from WebSphere for Developers downloads or if you have production license:
Web Server Plug-ins for IBM WebSphere Application Server Part 1 and Part 2
https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=swerpws-wasdevdl85

Then [install plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tins_webplugins.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en) and [configure for MS IIS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tins_manualWebIIS.html?lang=en)

Then [configure plugin to work with Liberty](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_admin_webserver_plugin.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-3-6&lang=en). Although this page is mentioning IBM Http Server, same configuration steps are for any web server supported by plugin.

Comment: All of my web/app servers go through an RP for security reasons. So regardless of whether I add IIS to the application server, the resulting output will still be going through the RP.